# Is the C++ syntax: T foo<U>; valid?

Tags: c++

The following code compiles and run with Clang (tested on 13, 14, and current git head), but not with GCC.

```
struct foo {
  int field<0, 1, int, 3>;
};
```

But I do not understand what it is declaring: what is this field ?

```
int field<0, 1, int, 3>;
```

I can put whatever I want in the `field<>` template (if it is even a template?), e.g. `field<0, 1, int, 3>` compiles and run. But I cannot access it afterwards.

Comment: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7rhq5Wvbe

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I said in my post that this is with clang

Comment: yes I misread, though it also was very different code initially

Comment: yeah I simplified it to the minimal thing that I found

Comment: Pretty clearly seems like a bug in clang! Also maybe NDR?

Comment: FTR, I just tried enabling all available warnings by adding `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Weverything` to godbolt.org's `-std=c++20 -O3`, but even that does not give any clues through warnings.

Comment: Fails as expected before Clang 9. I assume it is a regression.

Comment: Please report this as a bug, if you didn't already.

Comment: Bug reported to clang and already fixed, thanks to the crazy efficiency of @cor3ntin : https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/54151

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assuming `field` isn't a template that has been declared, the program is ill-formed.

> But I do not understand what it is declaring: what is this field ?

Clang AST says:

```
`-CXXRecordDecl 0xdb6f20 <test.cpp:1:1, line:3:1> line:1:8 struct foo definition
  `-FieldDecl 0xdb7168 <line:2:3> col:7 'int'
```

Clang AST for a program with `int field;`:

```
`-CXXRecordDecl 0x168af90 <test2.cpp:1:1, line:3:1> line:1:8 struct foo definition
  `-FieldDecl 0x168b150 <line:2:3, col:7> col:7 field 'int'
```

So, it looks like Clang thinks that an `int` field is being declared, but the name of the field is empty. This seems to be corroborated by being able to initialise this "unnamed" field:

```
foo f{0}; // compiles in Clang
```

---

The first Clang version to have this bug seems to be 9: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/d386oz8v8

Answer (score 9):

Without a declaration of `field`, this isn’t even valid **syntax**: the `<` can’t begin a template argument list, and expressions aren’t allowed there in a *member-declaration*.  (With a suitable declaration, it could be an invalid declaration with two types and no variables.)  Definitely diagnosable, and definitely a Clang bug.